# Combine Strings in json as single string using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json as follows:

```
{'body_text': [u'The',u'in Wynnewood, OK, just south of Oklahoma City,\xa0is h',u'eral different exotic animals:']}
```

How can I get output as:

```
{'body_text': [u'The in Wynnewood, OK, just south of Oklahoma City,\xa0is heral different exotic animals:']}
```

Comment: Have you considered writing some code?

Comment: what is the story with `heral`?

Comment: @Padraic random string, nothing much

Comment: I mean you have `h eral` and you have `heral` in your input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). This permits to join a list of strings, inserting another string in between:

```
d = {'body_text': [u'The',u'in Wynnewood, OK, just south of Oklahoma City,\xa0is h',u'eral different exotic animals:']}

d['body_text'] = ' '.join(d['body_text'])
print d
```

*Output*

```
{'body_text': 'The in Wynnewood, OK, just south of Oklahoma City,\xa0is h eral different exotic animals:'}
```